# ajax call does not handle gzipped JSON

Tags: jquery, jersey

I'm calling a service using jquery ajax(). The service is returning a gzipped data. However, the ajax function reporting an error that it cannot load the resource, any help?

My ajax call code is:

```
function crossJsonCall(url, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        cache: false,
        success: callback
    });
}
```

I zip the data using

```
com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter
```

Answer (score 2):

how about headers?

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  headers: { "Accept-Encoding" : "gzip" },
  ...
});
```

And, you need to make your httpserver send the appropriate headers. "content-encoding:gzip"